# npm install fails for node-grpc after nodejs 12 upgrade. Fails to build grpc_node with msbuild

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgraded nodejs version from 8 to 12 win my Windows 7 PC. after the upgrade, I cleaned the node_modules of my nodejs project and executed `npm install`. But it fails with following error.

```
  ......
  ......
  adler32.c
  compress.c
  crc32.c
  deflate.c
  gzclose.c
  gzlib.c
  gzread.c
  gzwrite.c
  infback.c
  inffast.c
  inflate.c
  inftrees.c
  trees.c
  uncompr.c
  zutil.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  z.vcxproj -> D:\projects\myproject\node_modules\grpc\build\Release\\libz.lib
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\program_files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "D:\\program_files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\program_files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\projects\\myproject\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=D:\\projects\\myproject\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\projects\myproject\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Any idea how to resolve this? I tried to upgrade my windows build tools by `npm install --global windows-build-tools`, but it still looks like npm uses same msbuild.exe in Program Files.

Comment: The grpc library distributes precompiled native addon binaries so that users don't have to build it at all. Near the beginning of your error output from running npm install, there should be an error message about trying to download one of those binaries. Can you include that error message in your question? It is difficult to build grpc on Windows, and it will be easier to fix that download error than to fix this compilation failure.